# How to recovering sharp edges on a triangular mesh

Tags: algorithm, 3d, geometry, mesh, edge-detection

I need some suggestions to be able to recover or recreate the edges in my mesh.
The mesh comes from a 3D scanner and the edges are therefore not well defined.
I implemented an edge detection algorithm to find all vertices and or triangles near the edge. (The red triangles are the ones under consideration.)

[image]

Now I need to know a way or a strategy to make the edges more marked. Can anyone suggest me some algorithm and or library to use?
Thanks.

Comment: @YvesDaoust now I upload a real scan with real edge quality.

Comment: this is a mesh file... triangulated from PointsCloaud.. i should work over mesh because this is the only output from scanhead.

Comment: You should have said 3D scanner !

Comment: it was obvious for me...  but I change the post with 3D scanner.